# I need to put several subscribers of different topics in one .cpp code

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, c++, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to put several subscribers of different topics in one .cpp code, in short'm starting to Subscribe all topics that provide information relating to TurtleBot2 and also like to know the topics with information that should really relaventes Subscribe, I'm using / odom bringing x , y, theta wanted to bring the covariance matrix also if someone tell me how to do it, and using cmd_vel to bring the x, y, what other topics related to sensors can Subscribe and how.

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198394/i-need-to-put-several-subscribers-of-different-topics-in-one-.cpp-code/) by [leobber](https://answers.ros.org/users/20424/leobber/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-11-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check available topics using

`rostopic list`

And use `rostopic info topic_name` and `rostopic type topic_name`  commands to know details about topic which you need to write subscriber.

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0